# Implementing my own enumerable method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I was implementing my own enumerable method using Ruby when I reach my_any? method. It doesn't pass some cases

my_any? works for some of the cases but others don't work

```
module Enumerable
    def my_each
       i = 0
       while i < size
         yield self[i]
         i += 1
       end
    end
   def my_any?
     if block_given?
       my_each {|item| return true if yield item}
     end
     false
   end
end
```

The below test cases are the require output

Test case 1

```
[4,8,true,18].my_any?  # => true
```

test case 2

```
[2,nil,5,true].my_any? # => true
```

test case 3

```
[nil,nil,nil,false].my_any? # => false
```

test case 4

```
[nil,nil,nil].my_any? # => false  # But my_any? fails this condition
```

Any Idea please

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results at all. In all 4 test cases, the result is `false`. In all 4 test cases, you do *not* pass a block, and if you don't pass a block, then your `my_any?` method immediately returns `false` without even looking at the elements at all. I have no idea how you managed to get `true` for the first two test cases, that is simply impossible.

Comment: Enumerable methods are intended to work when the receiver is an instance of any class that includes `Enumerable`. `my_each`, for example, does not work for hashes or ranges, which belong to classes `Hash` and `Range`, which include `Enumerable`. It appears that you have assumed the receiver of `my_each` is an array, in which case it should be defined in `Array`. It would be helpful to explain how you intend to use these methods.

Comment: This is sort of missing the core of Enumerable, and that's [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerator.html). Without that code like `my_each` is making huge assumptions about how it's supposed to iterate. Not everything has a size, and not everything can be indexed.

Comment: Yes my code is wrong any idea?

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's the desired output, not the actual output

Comment: "Yes my code is wrong any idea?" – Your code does literally nothing if you don't pass a block. So, the obvious first step would be: actually write some code that does something.

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_any?
  if block_given?
    my_each {|item| return true if yield item}
  end
  false
end
```

This method is immediately checking if it was called with a block and, if not, returns false. For example, `[].my_any?` will return false for `block_given?` while `[].my_any? { true }` will return true. None of your examples are passing a block, so they will always skip the if and return false.

The correct behavior of `any?` should be this: if a block is given, yield the value to it to determine if it satisfies the condition; if a block is *not* given, just check if the value is truthy.

```
def my_any?
  my_each do |item|
    if block_given?
      return true if yield item
    else
      return true if item
    end
  end
  false
end
```

or more succinctly

```
def my_any?
  my_each {|item| return true if block_given? ? yield(item) : item }
  false
end
```